# How to display images using XML?

Tags: xml, dtd

Hey guys. Does anyone know what do I have to enter in the DTD file in order to display an image from XML file?

Comment: What are you using to display your XML file?  XML files are text, and need to be processed into some other format to have pictures included.

Comment: You can store images in XML you you encode the in Base64

Comment: @Jenea: Yes, but they still won't show up as images unless you view them in a program that knows there is an image there.

Comment: I just want to load xml file into the browser in order to display it. That's it.

Comment: if you just want to load xml file into the browser in order to display it, then use XHTML: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little strange. Are you defining a new DTD? For what purpose? If you want to display images from XML, you may want to use XHTML. Its DTD has the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_img) element just for that purpose, and any Web browser knows how to render it.

In any case the XHTML DTD may serve as inspiration if you're defining your own DTD, but keep in mind that XML itself will not display any image: you need to process it (and that's what a Web browser does for XHTML).

Answer (score 0):

you need a xslt file to display pictures in the browser.

dtd describes the document structure
xslt can transform the xml document e.g. to html -> browser can show pictures.